# Let $U$ be open set in $\mathbb{R}$ and let $F$ be closed set in $\mathbb{R}$; show that $F\setminus U$ is closed in $\mathbb{R}$ (Proof verification)

Tags: real-analysis, solution-verification

Perhaps the question was already discussed in this forum. If so, sorry about the duplication. Below is a proposed proof for verification in case I missed something.

Since $U \subset \mathbb{R}$, $U = \mathbb{R} \setminus (\mathbb{R} \setminus U)$ so $\mathbb{R} \setminus (\mathbb{R} \setminus U)$ is open in $\mathbb{R}$. By the definition of closed set in $\mathbb{R}$, $\mathbb{R} \setminus U$ is closed.

Then we have $F \setminus U = F \cap (\mathbb{R} \setminus U)$.

Since $F \cap (\mathbb{R} \setminus U)$ is an arbitrary intersection of closed sets in $\mathbb{R}$ then $F \cap (\mathbb{R} \setminus U)$ is closed in $\mathbb{R}$. Therefore $F \setminus U$ is closed in $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: Yes, this is correct.